# Using Arquillian Persistence with Drone/Graphene

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian

Has anyone been able to use Arquillian Persistence extension with Arquillian Graphene/Selenium in the same test? I have a project that is using the Persistence & Drone/Graphene extensions and separately they both work fine. I can configure the database for integration tests with Persistence, and I can do UI Acceptance tests with Drone.

The problem is when I try to use the Persistence extension in a Drone test. For some reason the Persistence extension does not appear to execute as the database is never populated. Is there something special that needs to be done to enable the Persistence Extension to run in client mode with Arquillian?

**Test Class**

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@DataSource("java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS")
@UsingDataSet("OneUserAccount-Admin.yml")
public class LoginIT {

    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        return DeploymentFactory.getTemplateDeployment();
    }
    ...
    @Test
    public void testLogin() {
        this.openPage("login.xhtml");

        final IdLocator userNameField = id("loginform:email");
        final IdLocator passwordField = id("loginform:password");
        final IdLocator loginButton = id("loginform:loginButton");

        this.browser.type(userNameField, userName);
        this.browser.type(passwordField, password);
        waitForHttp(this.browser).click(loginButton);

        //Test Fails Here b/c Validation fails due to the user not being loaded to the database
    }
    ...
}
```

**Update**
I have tried removing the deployment=false and using @RunAsClient with no luck. I have also tried placing the @UsingDataSet and the @ApplyScriptBefore annotation on the test itself with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

After asking the same question on the Arquillian Forum, I was informed that this feature is not yet supported. I will file a JIRA Request to have it added shortly.

https://community.jboss.org/message/754432